# Get Path of a Static XML file in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

How do I read get the full path of a static XML file I added to my C# WCF project?

Comment: Are you asking for the path of the file in your project or the path it will be in when you execute your code?   How do you have the file set up in your project's build options?

Answer (score 1):

What is a "static XML file" for you?

You can use Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location in combination with Path.Combine if you want to access a file in the same directoy as your executable (or in any subdirectory).

Or did you compile it as a resource? Then, you can't access it via the file system.

Comment: This answer is as correct as mine: obviously, none of us can be sure what the questioner actually meant.

Answer (score 0):

When you added it, the file was copied into the directory where your csproj file is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're at development stage, you probably just hit F5 and your program runs.

It run from `bin\debug` folder, so you need to go up two levels and you'll be at your project root directory. If you created a folder to keep your static files, you'll need to do:

```
string myStaticXmlFilePath = @"..\..\StaticFiles\MyStaticXmlFile.xml";
```

Comment: I would imagine that the file is set to be copied to the output directory.

Comment: True enough.  However, without this, there's no guarantee that the file will be available after installation.